# About a decreasing sequence of convex domains

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$

Let $\Omega_n$ a decreasing sequence of open, bounded and convex domains in $R^n.$ Define

$$\Omega = \int \left(\overline{\bigcap \Omega_k}\right)$$

I am studying an article and appears that the author uses that $\partial \Omega_n \rightarrow \partial \Omega$ in the Hausdorff distance. this is true?

Maybe this help :

$A_n$ a decreasing sequence of open, bounded  domains in $R^n.$ Then

$$A_n \rightarrow  \int \left(\bigcap A_k\right)$$

in the Hausdorff distance.

I believe that i can give a positive answer for my question using the above result, but i dont know how to do this...

Comment: How do you define the Hausdorff distance between *open* sets? In my opinion, the natural way to do it is to use the distance between their boundaries. Otherwise, if the distance definition is applied verbatim to open sets, we end up with different sets having zero distance from each other.